# Activating "AND" Nodes and "OR" nodes

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, network-flow

Consider a directed graph with AND nodes and OR nodes. The AND nodes are activated only when all the in edges into it are activated. The OR nodes are activated if at least one of the in edges into it is activated. Assuming that vertices with no in edges into them are activated initially, how to design an **efficient algorithm** to decide if all nodes can be activated? I have thought of some naive algorithm but it takes $O(n^{3})$ time. I believe $n^{3}$ cannot be an efficient algorithm and there's some method that I am missing. Tagging domains where the problem might have a solution.

Comment: If there are no negation nodes, then isn't the problem essentially trivial?  The graph is monotonic, so activating more nodes will always be better than activating fewer; simply activate all of the 'root' nodes and then propagate. (If your question is essentially how to propagate, then you should be able to achieve at least $O(n^2)$ with minor modifications to a naive algorithm; you can certainly do better than that, but the graph theory starts getting a little trickier. Consider tracking the set of AND nodes all of whose inputs have been activated...

Comment: No. my question is not about how to propagate or any form of influence maximization. What if there are some set of AND nodes which are connected to each other mutually? Then these nodes will never be activated. This is one instance where the decision problem will give the answer that all jobs will not activate. I don't know if there are other possible instances which can prevent the jobs from activating. That's why I wanted to know an efficient algorithm. One question, is this problem then similar to finding a module in the graph?

Comment: Propagation really is the way to solve this problem. Start with all of the source nodes activated and, for each node, increment the 'activated input count' on all AND gates to which it's connected along an input line.  (OR gates propagate basically trivially). When this puts the number of activated inputs to an AND gate equal to its total number of inputs, put it in a 'fully activated' set. Then, for each node in the fully activated set, do the same propagation - increment the activated-inputs values on connected nodes and put any nodes with all inputs activated in the fully-activated set.

Comment: When you run out of nodes in the fully-activated set, do a final pass through your graph to see if there are any nodes that weren't activated.

Comment: Isn't this method in $O(n^{3})$ or is it less. Can you give a run time for this algorithm? What is the better runtime you were talking about? What tricks do we need to implement. I am all ears.

Comment: It will be substantially faster than $n^3$ with any halfway-decent implementation of the relevant data structures (even a stack should be just fine for this, though a queue is probably practically better); I won't give the specific runtime analysis because it shouldn't really be relevant, but you should be able to easily figure it out for yourself. (Hints: how often might you 'handle' a given node? How much work do you have to do when you handle a node?).

Comment: I wrote some code which I believe runs in $O((|V|+|E|) \log |V|)$; the extra factor of $\log |V|$ is because at several points I store the vertices in a hash structure.  You say you thought of some "naive algorithm" but you didn't say what it was so I don't know if my algorithm is  better than what you thought of, or whether it is the same and one of us mis-analyzed the running time.  I am reluctant to post my code because you rejected the answer that had C++ but you didn't say what you would prefer.  How would you like to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

A little modification to a dfs will work in time $\mathcal O(n^3)$. This dfs wil pass through each vertex at most $n$ times, so at most $n^2$ call to the function dfs are made, and each one takes at most $n$ iterations.

Here is the c++11 code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=1010;
int Ae[MAX]; // stores the number of activated edges going into a vertex
int A[MAX]; // stores if a node is activated
int In[MAX];// stores the number of edges going in
vector <int> Out[MAX];
int Ty[MAX]; // stores the type of node

void dfs(int x){
    if(Ty[x]==0) A[x]=1;// we check if the node should be activated
    if(Ty[x]==1 && Ae[x]== In[x]) A[x]=1;
    if(A[x]==0) return;// if not then we dont go into its neighbours
    for(int y: Out[x]){// otherwise we explore its neighbours
        if(Ae[y] < In[y]){
            Ae[y]++;
            if(A[y]==0) dfs(y);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n,m; 
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m);// read number of vertices and edges
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%d",&Ty[i]); // 1 if the node is AND and 0 if it is OR
    }
    while(m--){// read edges
        int a,b;
        scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
        Out[a].push_back(b);
        In[b]++;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){// we activate the vertices with in degree 0
        if(In[i] == 0 ){
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
    // at the end we can check if vertex i is activated using A[i]
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d: %d\n",i,A[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have that much of an experience in c++11. can you explain me your method. I also have an $O(n^{3})$ algorithm. I was wondering how to solve it in better time.

Comment: It seems to me that a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting), which can be done in $O(|V|+|E|)$ time, would be a better way to go.

Comment: How would it work?

Answer (score 0):

A idea would be to iterate over all edges, and from each edge see if a connected node is a AND or a OR node. Put at begin every node to true (activated) . If this node is a OR node, dont do nothing. If a edge is a activated node, we no need to do anything. If our edge is a not activated node, see if each of 2 nodes are OR nodes. If one of them is a AND node, and considering we have a not activated edge, we can assign this node to false (not activated) and exit inmediately, because we can return a value indicating that not all nodes are activated. Time of this algorythm is O(E). Daniel